# Can't find configure file

Tags: linux, vips

I'm trying to build libvips from source tarball and following the instructions.

https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/install.html

It's suppose to be a basic "./configure" "make" "make install" procedure, but there is no "configure" file in the source file I downloaded. There is a configure.ac file, but I'm not sure what to do about it, I only get errors when I run a "autoconf".

It feels like I'm missing something obvious here.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded a git snapshot instead of a release.

libvips has moved to its own organisation now:

https://github.com/libvips

Download from the libvips releases page:

https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases

You probably want vips-8.7.2.tar.gz, the current stable release. It includes the `configure` script.

If you really want to build from git master, you'll need to generate the build system yourself. Something like:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/my/install/prefix
make
make install
```

You'll need quite a few more packages to be able to run `autogen.sh` successfully. There are notes on the "install" page:

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/install.html

Having said all this, there's probably a libvips in your package manager, so I would just use that and not build from source, unless you are certain you need a recent feature.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it! I'm actually building all dependencies needed prior to this. I'm trying to package all the binaries and headers with my Go code for AWS Lamda.

Comment: Ah OK. There's a dockerfile for AWS here, it might be helpful: https://github.com/jcupitt/docker-builds/blob/master/libvips-amazonlinux-2018.03/Dockerfile